# Heroku No valid, non-passphrase-protected keys given error

Tags: heroku

I have this files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
STAR_mydomain_com.crt
TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt
USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
domain.key
```

domain.key is passphrase protected and it was generated during creation of CSR files (files that were required to get .crt files from certificate provider. I tried:

```
heroku certs:update certs/STAR_mydomain_com.crt certs/domain.key
```

But I get following error:

```
 !    No valid, non-passphrase-protected keys given.
```

How I can generate valid crt/key for heroku? (I tried all other crt files with domain key but they are not valid domain certificates.

---

domain.key was generated with following command:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out domain.key 2048
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to remove a passphrase from a private key:

```
openssl rsa -in certs/domain.key -out certs/domain-nopassphrase.key
```

You'll need to enter the current passphrase on the private key. If prompted for a passphrase on the new key, do not enter one (just press enter).

You can then update your SSL endpoint using your cert + this new key:

```
heroku certs:update certs/*.crt certs/domain-nopassphrase.key
```

Comment: When I try to execute `heroku certs:update...` heroku says `Resolving trust chain... done !    my-app-name has no SSL Endpoints.`. This is strange as app DOES have SSL endpoint addon installed (it costs 20$/month) - I can see it when I login to heroku dashboard....